# Fetched size and Installed Size

Tags: size, lightweight

i have 2 packages the first one has a Fetched 89.2 kb size  and it has 571 installed size ( lxterminal ) , and the other one has a Fetched 1738 kb size  and it has 502 installed size ( mlterm ) . how is it possible that a lighter Fetched size gives a heavier installed size ? and which one consider to be lighter

Comment: Which packages exactly?

Answer (score 0):

**mlterm** depends on **mlterm-common**:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mlterm mlterm-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,619 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,664 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

, which is 1.4M bytes. You've downloaded (and installed) two packages, not one.

Comment: sometimes the installed size is smaller than the Fetched size ? how comes ?

Comment: and did i mentioned that the second package should has a bigger installed size due to its bigger Fetched size but it is NOT it has a smaller installed size !!!!!!!!

Comment: Then the maintainer of the package did a mistake. `Installed-size` is only one line in control txt file. Report this as a bug.

Comment: what is the different between mlterm-common or the mlterm

Comment: The name, the contents and the size - nothing more.